# login clints to virtualized OS

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have ubuntu server 10.04 an install guest OS via VirtualBox. I am interested in how users through a LAN or the Internet can use (boot from yours PC) the virtualized OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the VM data on a shared network drive, then let everyone run VirtualBox locally. I have no idea how VirtualBox would handle locking in this case (if two people attempt to run the VM at the same time, chaos will ensue).

You can give the users ssh access to your server, and give them permission to access that VM. They will need a local X display to run the VirtualBox GUI or to interact with the machine's console.

You can set up the VM's network access so that it's visible from outside (the simplest way is to give it a bridged adapter, and make sure the corresponding IP address is routed properly), and boot the VM automatically on the server. Then people can log into it as if it was a physical machine (indeed, they don't need to know that it's a VM).